# Toggle not working properly in Firefox, Works in IE

Tags: javascript, firefox

Simple Toggle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#classes").click(function(){
    $("#class_breakdown").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

<a href="javascript:void(null)" id="classes" onclick="click(); return false;">View All Classes &raquo;</a>

<div id="class_breakdown">All Stuff Here</div>
```

IE works Great, however Firefox is expanding the div when clicked, and after it fully expands it collapses and returns to Display:None.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you have `onclick="click(); return false;"` in your element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing to much, you have to remove the `click()` in the onclick attribute because you already binding to the click event with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#classes").click(function(e){
    $("#class_breakdown").slideToggle("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

<a href="#" id="classes">View All Classes &raquo;</a>
```

I added `e.preventDefault()` instead of `return false` because it's works better cross-browser.

Comment: Using the above code but when I load an <iframe> from google maps the embeded map does not display ... Any thoughts on that? Again the code for the toggle works great but when toggling the embed code from a Google Map does not display

Comment: Its better to create a New question for this.